# Method undefined for a custom onclicklistener

Tags: android

I am using a custom onclicklistener in a ListViewAdapter. There is a button inside the list row. I need to pass some variables to the onclicklistener.

My problem is that I can't use 'startActivity() as I usually do to start an activity from an intent.

The warning says that the method startActivity is undefined for the type view.OnClickListener.

```
 private void setOnClick(final ImageButton mapButton, final String str){
            mapButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            Intent in = new Intent(context,
                                       Empresas_Mapa.class);
                               in.putExtra("nombre", titulo_evento);
                               in.putExtra("direccion", lugar_evento);
                               in.putExtra("lat", latitud_evento);
                               in.putExtra("lon", longitud_evento);

                               startActivity(in);


                       }
                });
            }
```

What should I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

startActivity() refer to view.OnClickListener which is wrong and OnclickListener doesn't provide a startActivity inside that , replace it with :

```
 YourActivity.this.startActivity(in)
```

Comment: Thank you Arash, but it doesn't work either, now the warning says that the method is undefined for MyActivity.

Comment: plz provide related codes , no one can help you more with these.

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure this method is in the Activity class

For the whole implementation, you can use a Map inside the Activity to store the relationship between View clickable (could be the row or the button) and the represented data.

In the onClick method, find the data by the View clicked from the Map, and pass the details data to the next Activity just like what you did.

Answer (score 0):

Use context.startActivity(in).it will work.